# C# campo decimal no Formulario

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, code-first

Questão simples:

Tenho um campo Decimal do tipo Currency no meu model. Ocorre que quando eu insiro um valor decimal no campo do formulario, ele chega como inteiro no Controller:

Exemplo:

Valor do KM Rodado: 0.41
Chega no Controller: 41

Meu Model:

```
[Required]
    [Display(Name = "KM")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "Valor deve ser uma quantia de dinheiro válida")]
    [Range(0.01, 9999.00)]
    public double ValorKM { get; set; }
```

Meu Controller:

```
ModelState.Remove("URLFoto");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(frota).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Meu Formulario:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValorKM)</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ValorKM, new { type = "text" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValorKM)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Outra questão é como faço pra alterar meu decimalSeparator. Trocar o "." por ","?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, primeiro recomendo utilizar `decimal` ao invés de `double` em:

```
public decimal ValorKM { get; set; }
```

E remova esse *dataType* `currency`, assim facilita e muito seu trabalho.

Segundo, na *view*, recomendo você utilizar um *plug-in* de formatação como o [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin).

Comment: Se alguém estiver com o mesmo problema, a única coisa que funcionou pra mim foi: <input type="number"  step="0.01">